# add task to nextflow and resume

Tags: nextflow

in test.nf (dsl2) I have

```
   ... 
   workflow{
       a = Channel...
       processA(a)
       processB(processA.out.emitA)
       processC(processB.out.emitB)
    }
```

The pipeline completed successfully.

Now I want to add `processC_2` that takes the output of processB.

How do I run the workflow to bypass processA execution?

I added processC_2 to test.nf and then did:

```
nextflow run test.nf -resume run-name
```

But it doesn't run the newly add process.

How do I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually very hard to answer this using only the information you have provided. It'd be necessary to actually see your `test.nf` file and read the processes. The execution seems right and I'd guess that the processB may be not emiting any output as shown in https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs.

It is also possible that when using the `-resume` together with a specific run-name you may be recovering the state of that specific run as shown here https://www.nextflow.io/blog/2019/demystifying-nextflow-resume.html. You can try to execute it without the run-name or without the `-resume` flag so you can check whether the problem is with the emition and channelling of outputs between processes, or with the `-resume` flag.